# convert multiple unix timestamps to dd/mm/yyyy from a data dump

Tags: php, date, unix-timestamp

I have a dump of members list in which there are 7000 users with joining date and subscription date in unix timestamp format . The thing is i need to import these members to a new membership software and it has dates in dd/mm/yyyy format . Now if have done such conversion for a single value coming from mysql database using

```
$datetime = strtotime($row->createdate);
$mysqldate = date("m/d/y g:i A", $datetime);
```

But how to convert almost 14000 such timestamps which are in between of strings of words ? is there anything that i can do or some way ?

Part of Dump

```
memberid,"identid","loginid","networkid","refurl_lookup_id","status","trial","joined","expired","last_login","stamp","siteid","username","password","cryptpass","ip","email","session","mailok","flat_price","first_login","third_party_partner_id","cascadeid","cascade_item_id","token","original_username","renamed","marked","token_hash","firstname","lastname","address1","address2","zip","city","country","state","shipping_firstname","shipping_lastname","shipping_address1","shipping_address2","shipping_zip","shipping_city","shipping_country","shipping_state","phone","xsell_success","xsell_message","custom1","custom2","custom3","custom4","custom5","last_modified","member_subscription_id","memberidx","billerid","statid","cost","cost_charge","spent","refunded","charges","next_rebill","optionid","rebills","active","upgradeid","expires","nats_expires","biller_expires","original_optionid","created_date","loginid_assigned","identid_assigned","gateway_token","campaignid","programid","tourid","adtoolid","subid1","subid2","countryid","promotionalid","loginid_nice"
7719,"26","0","0","27426","1","0","1398029330","0","1398797388","1398029330","1","torsten55","netsrot55","9dlO.AEZY3LpY","44776524","sds@googlemail.com","79ab391dc0873b7e18c63637d10d4a41","1","0","1398029433","0","1","1","0","sdsd","0","0","fb1d7da87c445cdfb59f241bd7e29dfe","dsd","Dietz","Karl-Liebknecht-Ring 22","","01612","Nuenchritz","DE","XX","","","","","","","","","","0","","","","","","","0","9866","CCBILL:02141107010sdsd","1","553543b62e8977","0","571","3938","0","1","1400707730","2","0","1","","1400707730","1400707730","0","2","1398029154","0","0","","0","0","1","0","0","0","0","0","Type-In"
7816,"45","0","0","30667","1","0","1398609314","0","1398797233","1398609314","1","Phantom183","MXU146","ac7Jo.tfvdJ5o","1573202729","rolex0@freenet.de","c29c6032ed3867b70ec7ec25749a1fde","1","0","1398609530","0","1","1","0","rolex","0","0","9446bf3e08c2e628cf449756ba92a9cb","sddso","Nasdal","BAhnhofstra&#195;&#159;e","","03046","Cottbus","DE","XX","","","","","","","","","","0","","","","","","","0","10043","CCBILL:021411770100000sd","1","5535d1545cd3f9","0","380","2627","0","1","1401287714","1","0","1","","1401287714","1401287714","0","4","1398609221","0","0","","0","0","4","0","0","0","0","0","Type-In"
```

Comment: Show us a portion of the data dump

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format

Comment: added dump @JohnConde

Comment: That's just a CSV file. If you want to manipulate this with PHP you can just use [PHP's built in CSV functionality](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) to read it in and then use `date()` to convert it to the proper format.

Comment: can you show any example of converting to timestamp it will be a help ill do it myself

Comment: http://ca1.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: are you importing into that software's DB directly? and it's got `dd/mm/yyyy` in the db? That'd suggest it's using varchar/text fields for timestamps, which doesn't bode well for the rest of the app...

Answer (score 0):

Just a basic example mostly copied from the manual:

```
if (($handle = fopen("olddump.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $fp = fopen('newdump.csv', 'w');
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        // Do this for each date field
        $data[7] = date('d/m/Y', $data[7]); // joined
        $data[9] = date('d/m/Y', $data[7]); // last_login
        // etc...

        fputcsv($fp, $data);
    }
    fclose($handle);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: thank you for you help but i am getting errors such as `A non well formed numeric value encountered in` and undefined `offset`